# unable to get the passed data from servlet

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I'm writing a program that is working fine with the regular jsp-servlet interaction. But when I submit the same with ajasx, it is not working fine. Below is my code.

**JSP-Servlet (w/o Ajax)**

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f1" id="f1" method="post" action="Controller">
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" /> <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nsme = request.getParameter("name1");
        request.setAttribute("name", nsme);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index1.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

**index1.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="${name}" />
</body>
</html>
```

***With Ajax***

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f1" id="f1">
        <input type="text" name="name1" id="name1" /> <input type="submit"
            name="x" id="x" />
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="SampleJS.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**SampleJS.js**

```
$('#x').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'Controller',
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
    });
});
```

**Controller**

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String nsme = request.getParameter("name1");
        request.setAttribute("name", nsme);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("index1.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
```

**index1.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" value="${name}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Here when I use the first method, The name is printed correctly. When I use it with AJAX, to my surprise nothing gets printed in the textbox.

Basically, We use `request.getRequestDispatcher("GetCaseData.jsp").forward(request, response);` to go to another page. What would be the alternative of it in my case?
please let me know where am I going wrong and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 2):

In the Ajax case you don't send any form data. Use `$.serialize` to serialize the form data and send it to the server:

```
$('#x').click(function() {
    var formData = $("#f1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'Controller',
        data : formData,
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data)
        },
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @wero, thanks for the quick reply . I've created  a sample for reference, what if I don't want to send any parameters, like, triggering  query 'select * from table'  and print the result in 'index1.jsp'

Comment: @user3872094 you don't need to send any data, the request body can be empty. But if you expect `request.getParameter()` to return some value on the server you should send some data.

Comment: Else I'll post the original after someone. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @user3872094 Regarding your question about SQL injection, the vulnerability is the same whether you are posting data through AJAX or not.  You'll want to defend against SQL injection either way on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

After adding ***formData*** in your js file

Check your browser **console**

You can find your whole **index1.jsp** html content printed in console 
with **${name} replaced with name you entered.**

**AJAX** calls are advised to be used to stay in same page and update page content without page refresh after call.

In above code with AJAX, you are in **index.jsp** only even after AJAX call completion.

You can switch to other page (**index1.jsp** in your case) after AJAX call by using javascript **window.location.href=<your file name >**. However in your case, the page switches to **index1.jsp** but as new request. You can observe the same in your **URL bar** of **browser**. As you are storing the **name attibute** in request scope. You wont see the value you entered in name field of index1.jsp.

Comment: Hi There, this is what is happening currently in my case, the data gets printed with values in console. I'm talking about my actual file. How can i fix this?